# buildSrc gradle folder not compiling

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

My goal is to have a common class that other build files can see in gradle.  I have created a folder called buildSrc and it is in my root directory of my android project.  The contents look like this:

```
    class CountryFlavors {

    def Closure getFlavor() {
        return  callback;
    }

Closure  callback ={

    mock {
        applicationId "ca.mysite.mock"
    }
    prod {
        applicationId "ca.mysite.prod"

    }
}

}
```

From the documentation it states that a class put into the folder buildSrc will automatically get put in the same classpath as my build script for android. But instead whats happening is the class cannot be found.  I tried to reference the class in build.gradle file on the app level but it cant find the class. Here is how i am calling the class CountryFlavors:

```
new CountryFlavors().getFlavor()
```

the compiler compains that this class cannot be found.  The class file is in buildSrc and i named it "build.gradle". i blanked out my root folder in the photo for proprietary reasons.   What am i missing ?[image]

my end goal is to have a class defined externally that can return a closure to me that i can use in my build script. @Opal

Answer (score 2):

Try on putting your CountryFlavor class in:

```
buildSrc/src/main/groovy/CountryFlavor.groovy
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

To answer your question I created a simple project. This is its simplified structure (I cut of .gradle, gradle wrapper etc):

```
C:.
|   build.gradle
|   settings.gradle
|               
+---buildSrc
|   |               
|   \---src
|       \---main
|           \---groovy
|                   CountryFlavors.groovy
```

build.gradle is simply:

```
task myTask << {
    println new CountryFlavors().getFlavor()
}
```

I put into getFlavor() method:

```
println "This is my callback"
```

Output is:

```
gradle -q myTask

This is my callback
CountryFlavors$_closure1@3ce443f9
```

Comment: It's not enough. `package` needs to be defined as well and such class **must** be imported at the beginning of gradle script.